# Laravel 4.2 Interface confusion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The default **User Model** in Laravel 4.2 implements both **UserInterface** and **RemindableInterface** but upon looking the definition of my User model, those methods defined on both interfaces are not implemented on the User model.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

How come it doesn't throw any errors when those methods defined on those two interfaces are not implemented by the User class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the `User` class uses two traits [`UserTrait`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/UserTrait.php) and [`RemindableTrait`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Reminders/RemindableTrait.php). If you check those traits, you will see the required methods are implemented there. So the `User` class doesn't need to implement those methods, as long as they are inherited. If you want, you could implement them and override/extend the inherited functionality.

Methods could also be inherited from parent classes as well. So here, the methods could be implemented by in the `Eloquent` class, that the `User` class extends (although that's not the case here).

You can read more on these subjects in the PHP Documentation:

> [Traits](https://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.traits.php)
>
> [Object Inheritance](https://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.inheritance.php)
>
> [Object Interfaces](https://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to look at those traits. I had the impression that methods to be implemented should be defined on the implementing class, in this case the User class.
P.S i'm just currently delving into php traits today.